# How to prepare holes in painted cement wall before attaching hose reel

Tags: cement, hole, weatherproof

I have drilled a few holes in the side of my painted cement wall and am about ready to attach a hose reel to the side (with provided cement anchors), however I would like to know if there are any weatherproofing preparations I need to do before I install the reel. Do I need to worry about water making its way into the area immediately surrounding the holes, or into the holes themselves?

(I used an SDS-Plus Rotary Hammer Drill with mortar bits to drill 1.5 inches into the wall)

[image: Overview of all holes in cement wall]
[image: Closeup of cement hole 1]
[image: Closeup of cement hole 2]
[image: Installation instructions for a concrete wall]

Comment: If you get freezing temps, place caulking/sealing in/around the holes to prevent water from freezing in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime I drill holes in exterior walls for screws or anchors, I squirt some caulk or sealer in the holes. This prevents any moisture from being absorbed into the wall. Moisture is never good in walls. You should also apply some around the outside of the holes to prevent water from seeping behind the existing paint. Remove any loose paint from around the opening.